# What does TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable mean?

Tags: python, list, integer, typeerror

Question: Find if there is a palindromic integer in the list.
Solution: I iterated over the integer variable which showed a Typographic error. After typecasting each integer of the list with a string I was able to iterate over the list.

Output gave Type-error: `'int' object is not sub-scriptable`

```py
def function(n, L):
    # checking if number i == reverse of this number which is raising error
    print(any(i==i[::-1] for i in L))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 5
    L = [2, 3, 5, 101, 42]
    function(n, L)
```

Comment: Please, share with us what you want to accomplish with the above `function()` function, so we can help you out.

Comment: Chaged L list of integers to list of strings. Then applied slice on its iterables.
Got that. Thanks.

Comment: This is a very confusing function. Could you include a description of what you want it to do?

Comment: And what's the role of `n`?

Comment: Please give more detail about what you want to do!!

Comment: The question was to find if the integer number(here i in list) in the list is a palindromic integer or not. So i tried to iterate over the integer variable which showed Typographic error. After typecasting each integer of list with string i was able to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`'int'` object is not subscriptable* means you try to use `[]` on an `int` variable

In you code, `L` is a list of integers, and you access each element in the for loop, then you try to take the `int` variable (represented as `i`) and access it with `i[::-1]`, which is a `Typeerror` since `i` is an `int` not a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check if an element is in a list you can use

```
n in L
```

Which returns True if n is an element of L

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find if there is the number n (or a string) in the list. If  I understood correctly, try to use this function, that is a bit more readable and that run.

```
    def function(n,L):
        print(any(n == x for x in L))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        n = 5
        L = [2, 3, 5, 101, 42]
        function(n, L)
```

Hope that was that you need

Comment: i wanted to check if the no in list is palindromic no or not. Actually when i iterate over the list the elements are integers so I cant iterate over the digits of integers when they are int. SO it typecasted them to string and then I iterate over them and i was successful to answer the question.